# Regex lookahead function for multiple characters

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I'm using the Wordle game to improve my regex skills by searching a 5 letter English word list using regex. The concept of the game that matters for this question is that the picture below shows information about a 5 letter US/English word. The grey letters do not appear in the word. The yellow letters appear in the word but not in the position indicated. I've developed a regex that solves this puzzle but it doesn't "look right" to me, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient and/or compact way to express myself?

[image: Wordle problem]

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | R | A (y) | C | K |
| F | I | E (y) | L | D |
| J | U (y) | M | P (y) | S (y) |

(y) = Yellow square

Here is my regex solution:

```
^(?=.{0,5}u)(?=.{0,5}e)(?=.{0,5}a)(?=.{0,5}p)(?=.{0,5}s)[^trckfildjm][^utrckfildjm][^aetrckfildjm][^ptrckfildjm][^strckfildjm]$
```

Note that for the second position I indicate (in addition to all the grey characters) that the letter "u" cannot be found there. The third position doesn't include "a" or "e", etc.

My main area of interest: I'm doing five independent character lookaheads, and I wonder if that could done more compactly or efficiently? Any suggestions for optimization or clarity would be welcome. Here's a regex sample with sample search word list to demonstrate fully: https://regex101.com/r/NkjXH9/1

Comment: If, as in your example, five distinct letters are known, you can simplify your expression. For your example you could use `^(?=.*u)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)(?=.*p)(?=.*s)[^t][^u][^ae][^p][^s]$`.

Comment: Efficient or not, based on what you know from your three guesses, any future guess must match the following regex, which states what letters must be present and what cannot be present and what we know are  present in the wrong position `^(?=.*u)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)(?=.*p)(?=.*s)(?!.*t)(?!.*r)(?!.*c)(?!.*k)(?!.*f)(?!.*i)(?!.*l)(?!.*d)(?!.*j)(?!.*m).[^u][^ae][^p][^s]$`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QWgBC/1)

Comment: Is this solved? Please paste your examples as text and not image.

Comment: @Kendle - based on the comments above, I conclude that my regex posed in the question is as efficient as it can be, both in performance and compactness. Should I post my original question as an answer? It doesn't seem right to do that..

Comment: @Kendle - weird - it's uploaded as a standard SO CDN image resource. Anyway, I recreated it with a markdown table, marking the fields that are yellow (right letter, wrong position). I'd welcome any input on this, as my regex "feels" like it could be more compact, but I can't figure out a simpler way to express it.